# ASP.NET Core Web API : get objects by a set of ids

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a request that takes in a list of ids and I want to return objects if they are found within that list.

For example

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ChatThread>> GetThreadByIDS(List<long> ids)
{
    // how do I query dbContext to get all chat threads based on a list of ids ?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public async Task<List<ChatThread>> GetThreadByIDS(List<long> ids)
{
     var result = await this.dbContext
                            .ChatThread
                            .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
                            .ToListAsync();

     return result;
}
```

Comment: Use the Async Entity Framework methods in production C# code.  The synchronous C# Entity Framework methods in most cases should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a list named `listOfIds` and your entity is `students`.

Then your query should be :

```
dbContext.Set<Student>()
         .Where(x => listOfIds.Contains(x.Id));
```